# Bounded positive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $\{a_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N} \in \Bbb R_+$ such that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=0 $$

Is it true that $\sup(a_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}<\infty$

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Hint: The limit being zero means that for some $N$ you have $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$ for all $n>N$.

Comment: ok @ThomasAndrews :-) thanks i understand now

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The limit being zero means that for some $N$ you have $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$ for all $n>N$.